# How to stop axios promise chain after a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How to break out of chain after a condition? I can't use try and catch because of the way I take the response(very bad response)

```
const fetchData = async dispatch => {
      await axios
        .get("/url.php?"})
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.success === false) {  
            setFetchingOk(false);
            logoutUser();

            //Here i want that the chain(everything below) to stop totally

          } else {
             // bla bla bla               
            return response.headerFields
          }
        })
        .then(headerFields => 
             //bla bla bla      
            )
        )
        .then(response => {
        });
    };
```

***Edit***: I solved it by throwing an error at my condition block like

```
throw new Error("Not authorized");
```

and then at the end of the chain adding

```
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Now it doesn't give Fatal Error

Comment: you can `throw` an error inside a `.then`

Comment: I deleted a lot of code to make it simple to read, probably I have messed up the brackets

Comment: sure, but that makes the code unreadable and hard to figure out what you want to do ... but, throwing an error or returning a Promise.reject() seem to be what you want to do

Comment: where do exactly I return a Promise.reject() ? at the line where I say i need to stop the rest of code?

Comment: I don't know ... where you want to "short circuit" your promise chain?